# Model Query Django

Tags: python, django, django-models

I'm trying to query fields from another model in Django .
I'm able to fetch the user information using  the following method

```
def student(self, *args, **kwargs):
        std_name = Attendance.objects.get(roll=self.roll)
        return std_name.name
```

Now I need to find the student's assigned teacher from a different table, I need to fetch it only using the student name which I got using student()  as I don't have any variable in my current table to reference it to fetch that information from the new table.

```
def teacher(self, *args, **kwargs):
        teacher_name = staff.objects.get(student=self.student)
        return teacher_name.name
```

But the above method is not working properly and is not populating the fields in my admin.py page . Can someone help me in fixing this issue

#Attendance model

```
class Attendance(models.Model):
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Attendance'
        verbose_name_plural = ''Attendance''

    
    Group = models.TextField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    Year = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    roll = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    Date = models.TextField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    name = models.TextField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    Presence = models.TextField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    
    
    def student(self, *args, **kwargs):
        std_name = Attendance.objects.get(roll=self.roll)
        return std_name.name

    
     def teacher(self, *args, **kwargs):
        teacher_name = staff.objects.get(student=self.student)
        return teacher_name.name
```

#staff model

```
class staff(models.Model):
    
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = staff
        verbose_name_plural = ''staff''
    name = models.TextField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
    degree = models.TextField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
    subject = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    experience = models.IntegerField(blank=True,null=True)
    student = models.TextField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
```

Comment: Please share your models...

Comment: edited the code